# When replacing some text in MS Word doesn't show newlines

Tags: c#, line, new-operator, cpu-word

I have a view in C# where I enter text with newlines. The following HTML helper is used:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.addText, 3, 150, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-lg-12", maxlength = "8000" })
```

In the controller I use the variable `addText` to include its content into a MS Word file.

Once I opened the Word file, the newlines don't show up. I tried to solve the problem by replacing `\r\n` with `<br/>`, `Environment.NewLine`, `<br/>` and `<w:br>` in the file, but the paragraph continues to show up without the newlines.

To make sure the MS Word file has newlines I execute this instruction and the Word file replace the newlines with the &&& characters.

```
"TextReplacer.SearchAndReplace("\r\n", "&&&")"
```

Thank for your time, I hope somebody has a solution.

Comment: Maybe you mean paragraph breaks?

Comment: I need to include newlines in a Word file.